# Return specific text from column if the formula returns an error excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have this formula:

=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(Monthly1!$A:$A,Table2!$B9,Monthly1!$J:$J,Table2!G$8,Monthly1!$L:$L,"P")/SUMIFS(Monthly1!$M:$M,Monthly1!$J:$J,Table2!G$8,Monthly1!$A:$A,Table2!$B9)-(SUMIFS(Monthly1!$M:$M,Monthly1!$J:$J,Table2!G$8,Monthly1!$A:$A,Table2!$B9,Monthly1!$K:$K,"W")+SUMIFS(Monthly1!$M:$M,Monthly1!$J:$J,Table2!G$8,Monthly1!$A:$A,Table2!$B9,Monthly1!$K:$K,"DNA")),"W")

Which counts the number of cells that meet specific conditions in a column in my Monthly sheet that is equal to P and divides the resulting number by the total of cells that meet specific conditions less the of the cells that meet specific conditions which contains DNA and W

What I need it to do is if the formula returns an error, it will search the qualifying cells for text:

scenario 1: if all qualifying cells contains DNA, the formula should return DNA

scenario 2: if all qualifying cells contains W, the formula should return W

scenario 3: if all qualifying cells contains both DNA and W, the formula should return DNA

Please help thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us ,, to text the formula you are trying so far!!

Comment: Could you provide the sample of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, for something like this, actual data, even if "fake-ified" after you copy a bit of it out, is a minimum for a literal solution if for no other reason than no one wants to do a lot of work and then find it was pointless because you didn't reveal a detail that matters.

Admittedly, it seems unlikely that would be so here, as the problem itself doesn't seem like it could pivot on something like that. But one still wants to test a literal solution before presenting it and that isn't gonna happen here. So...

General then.

The basic difficulty sounds like it is more particular than you literally state:  essentially it seems that by "returns an error" you mean "divides by 0." That seems so from the particulars that you focus on.

How would dividing by 0 occur? Well, if your divisor has the qualifying count and subtracts an equal value from it, you'll be dividing by 0. So trap that out before getting to the calculation by wrapping the basic formula ("basic formual" = drop the `IFERROR()` wrapping it) in an `IF()` test.

That test would compare the components of the divisor (which I am NOT NOT NOT gonna try to pull out) to each other for equality. If equal, the `IF()` would forget the thing you gave us and test for the two situations (yes, two, not the three you present) that are causing it. And since that is an either/or, you only have to physically perform one of the two tests to know the answer. So it would go like this:

```
=IF( "divisors are equal",
IF( "ANY of the qualifying cells contains DNA", "DNA", "W"),
"the basic formula you show (no `IFERROR()` function needed)"
)
```

In your tests at the end, test 1 and test 3 are basically the same thing. You want "DNA" returned if all are "DNA" or some are. In other words, you only want "W" returned if all of them are "W". So test for the existence of even a single "DNA" and return "DNA" if it is true. Return "W" only if none of them have "DNA".

What makes that work is there are no other subtractions from the divisor so only the either/or of those two needs evaluated. If there were other subtractions, it would just be more testing. Obnoxious but not complicated.

One supposes there is another possibility that give a divisor of 0 and that is if there are no qualifying cells at all. All that requires a simple test which you wrap the "basic function" in to see if the count of qualifying cells is 0.

However, you CAN simplify that (in appearance, os easier to maintain over time) if you **know for an ABSOLUTE fact** that there are **NO POSSIBLE" other reasons the data could yield an error. If the number of qualifying cells being zero is the only error that can occur in the basic formula, you can use the exisiting `IFERROR()` wrapper to trap that.

Notice, that ONLY works because you are trapping out the other possible error causes BEFORE reaching the portion you show in your Question. If you seek an alternate approach which does not trap the "divisor equals 0 because the count of cells with "DNA" or "W" equals the count of all qualifying cells" before using your formula, then the `IFERROR()` might fool you by trapping any of a hundred errors while you are thinking it only can get the one. Something to ALWAYS be watching out for before finally applying an `IFERROR()`.

And that should do it. Test before the calculation whether the divisor will equal 0 because of the "DNA" and "W" content branching to the simple text output if so and only moving on to the formula you presented if that is not true. Resolve the question of whether the qualifying count could equal 0 branching to a suitable result if it does, and only then commit to the formula you presented.

One more things to mention, applying to all Excel problems in one way or another, is "the real world" can help you out:  Resolving whether the count equaling 0 is a problem or not does NOT have to be done in Excel. You may know outside things that ensure this could never be so. If that is the case, yo needn't bother testing for the condition. **Do be sure though...**